# Draw line/route in the Bing/Google maps in Windows8 Metro App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a list contains sequence of latitude and longitude, like (example)

- [28.608329,77.198782]
- [27.608329,78.198782]
- [29.608329,79.198782]
- [30.608329,87.198782]
- [31.608329,97.198782]

I already got a code, that draws using 2 lant/long combinations.

`I have to draw line/route (like in Google Maps/Navigation) using all this sequence of sequence of latitude and longitude`. Is there any way available to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You have X points

- **Solution 1 :** Draw (X-1) routes
- **Solution 2 :** Draw A Polyline with X points (example with [MapPolyline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846499.aspx) (Bing Maps for metro style apps))

Answer (score 0):

Use the Shape Drawing Toolbox for the Bing Maps control: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Shape%20Toolbox%20Module